# Compile LaTeX to HTML/CSS with kept typography

Tags: pdftex, conversion

I have put lots of effort in the past to align, set and layout LaTeX documents as PDFs. Is there any reasonable converter, which uses CSS3, HTML, and so on to create a beautiful website from LaTeX. From what I see the well-known converters only keep the HTML very bare, and throw away the design.

If I cannot directly compile TeX to HTML, can you recommend some PDF converters, or other ways to publish LaTeX in a browser-centric way (not using PDFs)?

Comment: [pdf2htmlex](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/)  converts PDF to HTML without losing format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pdf2htmlEX](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/) can convert PDF to HTML without losing format.

Comment: pdf2htmlEX is no longer under active development.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently developing a free open source tool that can convert LaTeX to a single HTML file. Its called PDBF (https://github.com/uds-datalab/PDBF) and runs on win/linux/mac.

Instructions:

- Make sure you have a Java Runtime (version >= 1.7) installed
- Download latest version of PDBF: https://github.com/uds-datalab/PDBF/archive/gh-pages.zip
- Unpack archive
- Change current dir to unpacked folder
- Run: java -jar pdbf.jar /path/to/sometexfile.tex

Resulting HTML file is placed in the same folder as the source tex file with the same name as the source tex file.

Technical details:
The PDBF compiler basically uses a regular tex engine to compile your pdf and then stores the pdf as base64 encoded javascript string in the HTML and then includes a slightly modified version of pdf.js (The free and open source pdf engine of firefox) into the HTML to display that pdf.

Hope you like my project. Feel free to contact me through github if you have suggestions or encounter bugs.

Comment: Can you have a video to demonstrate this? It would really be helpful for students not well familiar with HTML.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the best I did was to convert the Latex file to pdf. Then the best and easiest thing to do is to convert the pdf to HTML5 using https://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdf-to-html5-converter/

This was the best and easiest possible method one may do to preserve all the structure of the latex file.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider [lwarp](https://ctan.org/pkg/lwarp?lang=en). It might require some work on your tex files, but it gives excellent output.